# MAMP htdocs phpinfo

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

I am trying to get a simple `phpinfo()` to print out on my local server (using MAMP).  I made a new directory in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs (php_sandbox)` and put a file in there named `my_phpinfo` with only `phpinfo()` in it.  How can I view the contents of this file in my web browser?

Is it also advisable if I set the Apache document root to be in my `home directory/sites`?  I will be mainly using this local server to test/host some small sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

visit in your browser `localhost/my_phpinfo/index.php` assuming you named the file with 
`<? phpinfo();?>` is in `index.php`. Also, make sure you are editing the correct php.ini in your MAMP directory by checking your mamp prefs and seeing what version of php MAMP is using.

Comment: Do you recommend using MAMP? I am now contemplating on installing mySQL/php separately. Learning it from the command-line might help me out later.

Comment: I love MAMP I have been developing web applications for about 10 years now and have used mamp for as long as I have known it exists.  you can still alias any of the cli tools with MAMP just read their docs

Comment: The only con I've experience with MAMP is trying to install / compile tools that depend on MySQL, PHP or Apache. For the longest time they didn't ship the zip php extension, and installing any other tools from pecl or pear can be a pita.

Answer (score 0):

Your in the right folder by default from what I remember. MAMP runs apache on port 8888 by default. You should be able to go to http://localhost:8888/ You can also get to this page via the control panel (should have a button to open home page). This page will also show you've configured MAMP's Apache to run on a different port.

Whatever you name your file; you'll want to give it a .php extension, so if you file is named `my_phpinfo`, add a .php so it becomes `my_phpinfo.php`. Make sure you function called is wrapped in php tags like so

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If this file is directory in the htdocs folder you should be able to go to http://localhost:8888/my_phpinfo.php and get the PHP Info page.

As far is moving the directory. I normally do. Especially b/c it makes upgrading MAMP a little easier (already have to worry about MySQL). You might have to tweak the file permissions just a bit to make sure it runs correctly. I believe though you should be okay since it is running as your User.